# HTML textarea curson indented for some reason

Tags: html, jsp

I need the cursor justified to the left.  For some reason its indented when rendering on the page:

```
             <td>
         You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH'] - fn:length(commentForm.comment)}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" style="width:395px;"
                 onkeypress="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)">
              </textarea>

                    <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

[image]

thanx for the help

Comment: I found it....I had whitespace before </textarea>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" style="width:395px;" onkeypress="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)" onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)" onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"></textarea>
```

Your closing `</textarea>` tag should always be on the same line to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Right!...that was the problem..thanx for the prompt reply